# Check that a a pop is closed with Selenium (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, testing, popup, webdriver

I'm writing some tests in java for a webpage with selenium. I see a lot of methods to ensure that an element is present on the page. But my need is to check that an element **is not present** on the page. More precisely, I need to check that the user has closed the pop up.

For the moment I see only methods to check that an element is present on thepage and not the contrary, like

> WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

Do you know if methods exists to to check that an element is not present on the page ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I verify that an element does not exist in Selenium 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353259/how-do-i-verify-that-an-element-does-not-exist-in-selenium-2)

Answer (score 1):

I **don't** think there is some method which checks if an `element` is present.

However, you could do

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.name("q"));
if(list.size()==0)
    System.out.println("Not Present")
```

`#findElements` returns a `list` containing the matching `WebElements`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try following:

```
public boolean isElementPresent(WebElement element){
try{
    element;
    return true;

    //element is present  
   }

catch(Exception e){

    return false;

    //element not present
   }

}
```