# Assert Absence of element in the web page, giving NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, nosuchelementexception

Need to assert that there is no such element in the webpage,
When tried with `fieldValueBox.isDisplayed();` instead of "false" its throwing "NoSuchElementFound" exception.
Right now i was using 'try catch' and making decision in 'catch'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the element is not on the page, then you will get 'NoSuchElementFound' exception. You can try checking that the number of elements with the locator is zero:

```
private boolean elementNotOnPage(){
    boolean elementIsNotOnPage = false;

    List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(yourLocator);

    if(element.size() == 0){
        elementIsNotOnPage = true;
    }

    return elementIsNotOnPage;

}
```

Comment: findElements(locator) would wait for elements (whatever amount of time you have defined in your test) , regardless of element is present or not. Sometimes a try catch would do the job in easier way.

Answer (score 1):

The `isDisplayed()` method returns a boolean based on an existing element. Meaning, if you want to check if an element, which exists, is displayed on the webpage or not (as in, not hidden or anything), this method will work properly.

In your case, its possible that the fieldValueBox does not exist. Because of this, the `isDisplayed()` method is going to try to return a boolean on a non-existing object.

A try catch is going to help you here, so that's one correct way. There are a few other ways, check:

[WebDriver: check if an element exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521270/webdriver-check-if-an-element-exists?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[How do I verify that an element does not exist in Selenium 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353259/how-do-i-verify-that-an-element-does-not-exist-in-selenium-2/6359753?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to *assert* that there is no such element in the webpage you have :

```
fieldValueBox.isDisplayed();
```

Now if you look into the *Java Docs* of [`isDisplayed()`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isDisplayed--) method it's associated to the [**Interface WebElement**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html). So before you invoke `isDisplayed()` method first you have to locate/search the element then only you can invoke `isDisplayed()`, `isEnabled()`, `isSelected()` or any other associated methods.

Of-coarse, in your previous steps when you tried to find/locate the desired *WebElement* through either `findElement(By by)` or `findElements(By by)` method **NoSuchElementFound** exception was raised. When `findElement(By by)` or `findElements(By by)` method raises **NoSuchElementFound** exception ofcoarse the following line of `fieldValueBox.isDisplayed();` won't be executed.

### Solution

A possible solution for your problem would be to invoke `findElement(By by)` within a `try-catch {}` block as follows :

```
try {
    WebElement fieldValueBox = driver.findElement(By.id("element_id"));
    bool displayed = fieldValueBox.isDisplayed();
    //use the bool value of displayed variable
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    //perform other tasks
}
```