# How to select locator for checkboxes

Tags: selenium, checkbox, path, testng

Here I have to select the checkbox using `selenium` and I'm not able to select it. It has only one option of classname that I'm using but error is appearing:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to                locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"um-icon-android-checkbox-outline"}

code

```
@Test
public void validemail()
{
    WebElement email=driver.findElement(By.id("username-15"));
    email.clear();
    email.sendKeys("ceicateviewer");

    WebElement password=driver.findElement(By.id("user_password-15"));
    password.clear();
    password.sendKeys("1256Aa");

    WebElement showpassword=driver.findElement(By.className("um-icon-android-checkbox-outline"));
    showpassword.click();

    WebElement keepsignin=driver.findElement(By.className("um-icon-android-checkbox-outline"));
    keepsignin.click();


    /*WebElement login=driver.findElement(By.className("um-button"));
    login.click();*/
}
```

Comment: Could you show us HTML to your checkbox?

Comment: In order to locate correct xpath, There should be HTML block in question. Please add it.

Comment: (By.xpath("//i[@class='um-icon-android-checkbox-outline-blank']")); but still its not able to find out

Comment: People are asking you to share HTML

Comment: @shwetakaushik Check this discussion to address [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49794733/assert-absence-of-element-in-the-web-page-giving-nosuchelementexception/49795969#49795969)

Answer (score 0):

So, I get from your code, that it seems that checkbox `showpassword` and checkbox `keepsignin` have the same classname. That means, there are at least 2 elements have classname `um-icon-android-checkbox-outline`, that's why when you use `driver.findElement`, driver doesn't know which one. In this case you have to use `driver.findElements`. You can try this:

```
List<WebElement> checkboxes = driver.findElements(By.className("um-icon-android-checkbox-outline"));
// assuming there are only 2 elements have this classname, and in this order
checkboxes.get(0).click();  // click on showpassword
checkboxes.get(1).click();  // click on keepsignin
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: if i am using this code then(it throws this error):::::java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 List cannot be resolved to a type
 get cannot be resolved
 List cannot be resolved to a type
 get cannot be resolved

Comment: @shwetakaushik: is `import java.util.List` present in your Imports? The error indicates that you might use the wrong import.

Comment: import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
I USED THIS IMPORTS WITH    CODE  List<WebElement>showpassword=get.driver.findElement(By.className("um-icon-android-checkbox-outline"));   showpassword.get.click();
List<WebElement> keepsignin=get.driver.findElement(By.xpath("um-icon-android-checkbox-outline"));
keepsignin.get.click(); THEN IT GIVES ERROR java.lang.Error:  get cannot be resolved @Ragnarsson

Comment: @shwetakaushik well, you did wrong in your code. 1) why `get.driver.findElement` ?!. I don't get it. that's why you got that's error `get cannot be resolved`. 2) `findElement` return a single WebElement, not a List. Please check my answer again.